# Testdroid/Robotium waitForFragment using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, robotium, testdroid

I am trying to use Testdroid which is backed by Robotium.

Background:
`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does not assign tag values for fragments (unlike `FragmentPagerAdapter`) so `waitForFragmentByTag` won't work; as a result I use `waitForFragmentById`, which I am unable to get working as expected.

My fragments are defined in xml (*fragment.xml*) which defines the UI structure and layout.
My fragments are also defined in code (*Fragment.java*), which is where listeners are registered etc.

I have debugged through the `ExtSolo` source code and when the `Waiter` calls the fragmentManager (both) null values are returned for both the ID defined in the @id tag of the parent element in the XML (`R.id.fragment`) and also the ID defined by the file itself (`R.layout.fragment`).

Are these the correct ID values to be using? If not, what is? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a nasty work around which will cause tests to fail if structure changes:

```
private void assertAtHomeFragment() {
    assertTrue(solo.waitForView(ListView.class, 1, 2000));
    assertTrue(solo.waitForView(ImageButton.class, 3, 2000));
    assertTrue(solo.waitForView(Button.class, 1, 2000));
    solo.sleep(1000);
}

private void assertAtLibraryFragment() {
    assertTrue(solo.waitForView(ListView.class, 1, 2000));
    assertTrue(solo.waitForView(ImageButton.class, 0, 2000));
    solo.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Robotium bases on FragmentManager and method findFragmentById/findFragemntByTag.
With sample application Support4Demos, I checked fragments in State Pager, what seems to be similar to your context. Using this code:

```
List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    if (!fragList.contains(fragment)) {
        fragList.add(fragment);
        Log.d("TEST", "Fragment id ("+ fragment.getId() +")");
        if (fragment.getId() != View.NO_ID && fragment.getId() != 0) {
            String id = fragment.getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                    fragment.getId());
            Log.d("TEST", "Fragment id " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

you can check, what id your fragments have. Unfortunately they all have id of ViewPager or id = 0, so it seems to be impossible to distinguish them by id. Don't know, if it will help you, but I hope so.